# PyQt view model methods for qtreewidget

Tags: python, qt, widget, pyside

I'm not certain how Qt's model/view system works... they claim the qtreewidget widget uses it, but I can't see how its working.

What I want to do is have the qtreewidget nodes point to a data object, and just override the methods the UI uses to display the data. Could someone show me how to override these methods?

Here is my data object...

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, name="", age=0, children=None):
        self.name = name
        self.uid = str( uuid.uuid4( ) )
        self.age = age
        self.children = children if children is not None else []
```

I couldn't see where to make this work, but in theory I think it would look something like this:

```
class CustomTreeNode( QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem ):
    def __init__( self, parent, car ): # Only supply the car, you will see why down below
        super( CustomTreeNode, self ).__init__( parent )
        self.car_data = car

    def getText( self, col ):
        # Override whatever internal method the UI calls to query the text value before painting itself
        # --- this would always just reflect the Car instance's value instead of trying to synchronize all of the TreeItems

        return self.car_data.name


    def getFont( self, col ):
        # Likewise for painting the selected items bolded --

        # Over in your treewidget on selection changed events, you'd store off the selected cars:
        # --- self.selected_cars = set( [ item.car_data for item in event.selection ] )

        # Then here when the UI queries the font to render it would do something like this:

        if self.car_data in self.tree_widget.selected_cars:
              return FONTS.get_font("accent")
        else:
              return FONTS.get_font("regular")
```

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do? It seems like you may want to use views/model instead, as a custom model will give you lots of flexibility in how you present your data.

Comment: You should look at [delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstyleditemdelegate.html) too.

Comment: @101 I'm wanting to display each of my class objects in the treeview. If the class object has children then those are displayed under their corresponding parent and so forth. Would you be able to help?